# C++ how to implement const iterator for custom container

Tags: c++, collections, iterator, containers

I have this container:

`using platform_route_container = std::unordered_map< std::pair< std::string, std::string>, std::set< packed_time>>;`

It is an unordered map of pair bus platform and route as key, and set of departure times as value.
I need to implement an iterator for it with ++ arithmetics. This global method will return the iterator which points at the place in container std::set< packed_time> of departures pr at a given time tm.

`route_departure_const_iterator departure_at(platform_route_const_reference pr, packed_time tm);`

`using route_departure_const_iterator = route_departure_container::const_iterator;`

How can I implement such an iterator? Thanks!

Comment: Why would you want to implement that iterator? `std::set` already has its own `const_iterator`. Are you asking for the type of that iterator?

Comment: You don't.  Your "global method" will need to return a `std::set<packed_time>::const_iterator`  (which is already implemented by `std::set`).    The logic of your "global method" will first need to retrieve (reference to) `std::set<packed_time>` that contains the `packed_time` you seek from the unordered map.   If such a set isn't found, return an end iterator.   If such a set is found, then obtain the iterator from that set.